# rviz2 not loading "Entry Point Not Found"(Windows)

Tags: environment-variables, ros, entry-point, rviz

I am having issues when trying to launch Rviz2.

I get two "Entry Point Not Found" errors, both .dll's are located in the directories shown in the erros.

Error1:

```
" The procedure entry point ?hasEdgeList@MovableObject@Ogre@@UEAA_NXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin\rviz_common.dll. "
```

Error 2:

```
" The procedure entry point ?coulour@ManualObject@Ogre@@UEAAXAEBVColourValue@2@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin\rviz_rendering.dll. "
```

I have already set C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin in my PATH environment variables, but the error doesn't disappear.

Comment: How did you install rviz? And did you make sure to source the right setup file?

Comment: I installed it following this tutorial https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html which shows how to install ros2 foxy on windows. It always worked for me until today when I couldn't open Rviz...

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ros2 run rviz2 rviz2`, instead.
I'm just trying to get my windows install working as well.